# How to deal with if/else like this in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to display content in a Bootstrap panel, the first two of the groups go in panel one, the next in panel two and the last two in a third and last panel. Each panel sits in a 1/3 column using Bootstrap grid. I can't wrap my head around how I should fix this in HAML:

```
.row
  - x = 0
  / @educations is a grouped query by study_year, for each 2 study years (out of 6) 
  / I would like to display the educations that belong to it in the same panel
  - @educations.each do |study_year, education|
    - if x%2 == 0 // makes sure panel is only rendered once for every two iterations
      .col-sm-4
        .panel.panel-default
          .panel-heading= "Studyyear #{study_year.name}"
          %ul.list-group= render education
    - else
          %ul.list-group= render education // this gives nesting too deep error
    - x = x +1
```

Reducing the indent of the last ul.list-group results in the content not being displayed inside the panel.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I _think_ you need to look at [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to group your objects, but I don’t know the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just do:

```
row
  - x = 0
  / @educations is a grouped query by study_year, for each 2 study years (out of 6) 
  / I would like to display the educations that belong to it in the same panel
  - @educations.each do |study_year, education|
    - if x%2 == 0 // makes sure panel is only rendered once for every two iterations
      .col-sm-4
        .panel.panel-default
          .panel-heading= "Studyyear #{study_year.name}"
          %ul.list-group= render education
    - else
        .div
          %ul.list-group= render education // this gives nesting too deep error
    - x = x +1
```